# Does Snowflake monitor "Snowflake Ideas Pages" and act?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I thought of posting an idea on [Snowflake Ideas Page](https://community.snowflake.com/s/ideas) and I see as of this posting date, there are 587 ideas listed. Out of which 585 ideas status is still listed as *New Idea*, 1 idea *on Roadmap* and 1 idea *under construction*. These two ideas that have some progress is about updating something on community site. It doesn't look like Ideas are being actively monitored and acted to provide response on the progress of any of the ideas. Disappointing and not sure if it even worth posting it there.

Comment: This isn't an appropriate question for Stackoverflow, but I do recommend posting your idea to those pages.  They are seen by Snowflake even if the status isn't updated very frequently.

Comment: Thank you and may make sense, but was curious to know if anyone on the forum had feedback on their experience on ideas that they would have submitted. As stack overflow is recommended technical forum on Snowflake's site, I am pretty sure Snowflake would monitor this forum as well and this could help Snowflake as a feedback. It helps and motivates posters who submit ideas to know the status of their ideas as it would encourage them to contribute more. Just my two cents.